# ASP.NET Core MVC view localization

Tags: asp.net, razor, localization, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC and let's say I have the following Razor view:

```
@model AwesomeApp.ViewModels.User

<h1>
    User <span class="user">@Model.Username</span> has reached <span class="level">@Model.Level</span> level!
</h1>
```

Now I want to localize it:

```
@model AwesomeApp.ViewModels.User
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

<h1>
    @Localizer["LevelUp", Model.Username, Model.Level]
</h1>
```

In my **.resx** file I have a resource with a key **LevelUp**:

```
User <span class="user">{0}</span> has reached <span class="level">{1}</span> level
```

That is working fine, but I do not want to keep HTML tags in the **.resx** file, I just want to keep rendered text only:

> User {0} has reached {1} level!

Is there a way to do it with either `IViewLocalizer` or by utilizing `Localization.AspNetCore.TagHelpers` ?

Comment: Simply, no. If you want the tags in the resulting localized string, they need to be in your resource file that way.

Comment: That said, you could probably actually do something like `@Localizer["LevelUp", $"<span class=\"user\">{Model.Username}</span>", $"<span class=\"level\">{Model.Level}</span>"]`. In other words, you sub in the whole HTML construction for the username/level instead of just the username/level itself. However, that's a pretty significant code-smell, especially if you end up using this same thing in multiple places. Ultimately, it's preferable to simply put the HTML in your resource file.

Comment: @Chris Pratt, Are you sure ? An official [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1) mentioned that `You generally want to only localize text and not HTML.`

Comment: And that's true, but with the code you want (username and level wrapped in spans) you *must* - hence the "generally". In other words, the best thing is to avoid using HTML in the things you're localizing at all, but if you need the HTML there for some reason, then you can.

Answer (score 1):

For those finding this from google now, I was able to do this in ASP.Net Core 3.1 (not sure about other versions).

Putting HTML in the parameter to the resource key, as suggested in [a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969864/asp-net-core-mvc-view-localization#comment90890797_51969864), won't work because parameters are HTML encoded:
[image: screenshot of intellisense text]

However, it is close and I was able solve it with `@Html.Raw()` and the `Localizer.GetString()` method:

`@Html.Raw( Localizer.GetString( "LevelUp", $"<span class=\"user\">{Model.Username}</span>", $"<span class=\"level\">{Model.Level}</span>" ) )`

And change the resx value for `LevelUp` to: `User {0} has reached level {1}`

The key here is that GetString doesn't return an `LocalizedHtmlString`, it returns a `LocalizedString` which you then can output as raw HTML.

For clarity if you're doing the format where the default language translation is the key (rather than some slug like `LevelUp`), it would look like this:
`@Html.Raw( Localizer.GetString( "User {0} has reached level {1}", $"<span class=\"user\">{Model.Username}</span>", $"<span class=\"level\">{Model.Level}</span>" ) )`

And, as a bonus, you can also use `GetString` inside the arguments like so:
`@Html.Raw( Localizer.GetString( "Click {0} to do something...", $"<a href=\"whatever-link\">{Localizer.GetString("here")}</span>" )`